# What is the most efficient technique/practice for enumerating object properties?

Tags: javascript

I need the most efficient way to enumerate the own properties of an object in Javascript. I'm of course aware of the `for...in` pattern, but according to my tests, it is really a performance gotcha in some scenarios and I would like to work it around somehow.

To be clear, I mean the following basic snippet.

```
for (var key in myObject) {
  if (!myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
  ...
}
```

I've been thinking about some kind of caching but that's not trivial and also would not allow to catch the properties real-time.

Any suggestions or hints are appreciated.

UPDATE

Turned out based on my small performance test that in a modern browser `Object.keys` can have huge advantage over other techniques.

http://jsperf.com/enumerating-object-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you tried [getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) ? or even [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)?

can you also share the results of performance testing you have done?

Comment: Thank you, I can learn something new here every day. I wasn't aware of these methods. Actually I've put together a test and it came out that Object.keys is significantly faster than the others (at least in Chrome 46). Here is the test: http://jsperf.com/enumerating-object-properties

Comment: Now in end of 2016 interestingly enough it seems like the `for...in` loop is significantly faster than the others in latest Chrome.